# how to avoid text limit on one line or any advise on my code.. please

Tags: python

I wrote def which make program give me the result only when the city is in the list.
But the number of city is a lot.. so it exceeds the limit of the charter on one line.
Any one can give me an idea to deal with this problem?

```
def is_allowed_location(location):
return 'Alabama' in location or 'Alaska' in location or 'Arizona' in location or 'Arkansas' in location or 'California' in location or 'Colorado' in location or 'Connecticut' in location or 'Delaware' in location or 'Florida' in location or 'Georgia' in location or 'Hawaii' in location or 'Idaho' in location or 'Illinois' in location or 'Indiana' in location or 'Iowa' in location or 'Kansas' in location or 'Kentucky' in location or 'Louisiana' in location or 'Maine' in location or 'Maryland' in location or 'Massachusetts' in location or 'Michigan' in location or 'Minnesota' in location or 'Mississippi' in location or 'Missouri' in location or 'Montana' in location or 'Nebraska' in location or 'Nevada' in location or 'New Hampshire' in location or 'New Jersey' in location or 'New Mexico' in location or 'New York' in location or 'North Carolina' in location or 'North Dakota' in location or 'Ohio' in location or 'Oklahoma' in location or 'Oregon' in location or 'Pennsylvania' in location or 'Rhode Island' in location or 'South Carolina' in location or 'South Dakota' in location or 'Tennessee' in location or 'Texas' in location or 'Utah' in location or 'Vermont' in location or 'Virginia' in location or 'Washington' in location or 'West Virginia' in location or 'Wisconsin' in location or 'Wyoming' in location or 'AL' in location or 'AK' in location or 'AZ' in location or 'AR' in location or 'CA' in location or 'CO' in location or 'CT' in location or 'DE' in location or 'FL' in location or 'GA' in location or 'HI' in location or 'ID' in location or 'IL' in location or 'IN' in location or 'IA' in location or 'KS' in location or 'KY' in location or 'LA' in location or 'ME' in location or 'MD' in location or 'MA' in location or 'MI' in location or 'MN' in location or 'MS' in location or 'MO' in location or 'MT' in location or 'NE' in location or 'NV' in location or 'NH' in location or 'NJ' in location or 'NM' in location or 'NY' in location or 'NC' in location or 'ND' in location or 'OH' in location or 'OK' in location or 'OR' in location or 'PA' in location or 'RI' in location or 'SC' in location or 'SD' in location or 'TN' in location or 'TX' in location or 'UT' in location or 'VT' in location or 'VA' in location or 'WA' in location or 'WV' in location or 'WI' in location or 'WY' in location or 'alabama' in location or 'alaska' in location or 'arizona' in location or 'arkansas' in location or 'california' in location or 'colorado' in location or 'connecticut' in location or 'delaware' in location or 'florida' in location or 'georgia' in location or 'hawaii' in location or 'idaho' in location or 'illinois' in location or 'indiana' in location or 'iowa' in location or 'kansas' in location or 'kentucky' in location or 'louisiana' in location or 'maine' in location or 'maryland' in location or 'massachusetts' in location or 'michigan' in location or 'minnesota' in location or 'mississippi' in location or 'missouri' in location or 'montana' in location or 'nebraska' in location or 'nevada' in location or 'new hampshire' in location or 'new jersey' in location or 'new mexico' in location or 'new york' in location or 'north carolina' in location or 'north dakota' in location or 'ohio' in location or 'oklahoma' in location or 'oregon' in location or 'pennsylvania' in location or 'rhode island' in location or 'south carolina' in location or 'south dakota' in location or 'tennessee' in location or 'texas' in location or 'utah' in location or 'vermont' in location or 'virginia' in location or 'washington' in location or 'west Virginia' in location or 'wisconsin' in location or 'wyoming' in location or 'Alexander City' in location or 'Andalusia' in location or 'Anniston' in location or 'Athens' in location or 'Atmore' in location or 'Auburn' in location or 'Bessemer' in location or 'Birmingham' in location or 'Chickasaw' in location or 'Clanton' in location or 'Cullman' in location or 'Decatur' in location or 'Demopolis' in location or 'Dothan' in location or 'Enterprise' in location or 'Eufaula' in location or 'Florence' in location or 'Fort Payne' in location or 'Gadsden' in location or 'Greenville' in location or 'Guntersville' in location or 'Huntsville' in location or 'Jasper' in location or 'Marion' in location or 'Mobile' in location or 'Montgomery' in location or 'Opelika' in location or 'Ozark' in location or 'Phenix City' in location or 'Prichard' in location or 'Scottsboro' in location or 'Selma' in location or 'Sheffield' in location or 'Sylacauga' in location or 'Talladega' in location or 'Troy' in location or 'Tuscaloosa' in location or 'Tuscumbia' in location or 'Tuskegee' in location or 'Alaska' in location or 'Anchorage' in location or 'Cordova' in location or 'Fairbanks' in location or 'Haines' in location or 'Homer' in location or 'Juneau' in location or 'Ketchikan' in location or 'Kodiak' in location or 'Kotzebue' in location or 'Nome' in location or 'Palmer' in location or 'Seward' in location or 'Sitka' in location or 'Skagway' in location or 'Valdez' in location or 'Arizona' in location or 'Ajo' in location or 'Avondale' in location or 'Bisbee' in location or 'Casa Grande' in location or 'Chandler' in location or 'Clifton' in location or 'Douglas' in location or 'Flagstaff' in location or 'Florence' in location or 'Gila Bend' in location or 'Glendale' in location or 'Globe' in location or 'Kingman' in location or 'Lake Havasu City' in location or 'Mesa' in location or 'Nogales' in location or 'Oraibi' in location or 'Phoenix' in location or 'Prescott' in location or 'Scottsdale' in location or 'Sierra Vista' in location or 'Tempe' in location or 'Tombstone' in location or 'Tucson' in location or 'Walpi' in location or 'Window Rock' in location or 'Winslow' in location or 'Yuma' in location or 'Arkansas' in location or 'Arkadelphia' in location or 'Arkansas Post' in location or 'Batesville' in location or 'Benton' in location or 'Blytheville' in location or 'Camden' in location or 'Conway' in location or 'Crossett' in location or 'El Dorado' in location or 'Fayetteville' in location or 'Forrest City' in location or 'Fort Smith' in location or 'Harrison' in location or 'Helena' in location or 'Hope' in location or 'Hot Springs' in location or 'Jacksonville' in location or 'Jonesboro' in location or 'Little Rock' in location or 'Magnolia' in location or 'Morrilton' in location or 'Newport' in location or 'North Little Rock' in location or 'Osceola' in location or 'Pine Bluff' in location or 'Rogers' in location or 'Searcy' in location or 'Stuttgart' in location or 'Van Buren' in location or 'West Memphis' in location or 'California' in location or 'Alameda' in location or 'Alhambra' in location or 'Anaheim' in location or 'Antioch' in location or 'Arcadia' in location or 'Bakersfield' in location or 'Barstow' in location or 'Belmont' in location or 'Berkeley' in location or 'Beverly Hills' in location or 'Brea' in location or 'Buena Park' in location or 'Burbank' in location or 'Calexico' in location or 'Calistoga' in location or 'Carlsbad' in location or 'Carmel' in location or 'Chico' in location or 'Chula Vista' in location or 'Claremont' in location or 'Compton' in location or 'Concord' in location or 'Corona' in location or 'Coronado' in location or 'Costa Mesa' in location or 'Culver City' in location or 'Daly City' in location or 'Davis' in location or 'Downey' in location or 'El Centro' in location or 'El Cerrito' in location or 'El Monte' in location or 'Escondido' in location or 'Eureka' in location or 'Fairfield' in location or 'Fontana' in location or 'Fremont' in location or 'Fresno' in location or 'Fullerton' in location or 'Garden Grove' in location or 'Glendale' in location or 'Hayward' in location or 'Hollywood' in location or 'Huntington Beach' in location or 'Indio' in location or 'Inglewood' in location or 'Irvine' in location or 'La Habra' in location or 'Laguna Beach' in location or 'Lancaster' in location or 'Livermore' in location or 'Lodi' in location or 'Lompoc' in location or 'Long Beach' in location or 'Los Angeles' in location or 'Malibu' in location or 'Martinez' in location or 'Marysville' in location or 'Menlo Park' in location or 'Merced' in location or 'Modesto' in location or 'Monterey' in location or 'Mountain View' in location or 'Napa' in location or 'Needles' in location or 'Newport Beach' in location or 'Norwalk' in location or 'Novato' in location or 'Oakland' in location or 'Oceanside' in location or 'Ojai' in location or 'Ontario' in location or 'Orange' in location or 'Oroville' in location or 'Oxnard' in location or 'Pacific Grove' in location or 'Palm Springs' in location or 'Palmdale' in location or 'Palo Alto' in location or 'Pasadena' in location or 'Petaluma' in location or 'Pomona' in location or 'Port Hueneme' in location or 'Rancho Cucamonga' in location or 'Red Bluff' in location or 'Redding' in location or 'Redlands' in location or 'Redondo Beach' in location or 'Redwood City' in location or 'Richmond' in location or 'Riverside' in location or 'Roseville' in location or 'Sacramento' in location or 'Salinas' in location or 'San Bernardino' in location or 'San Clemente' in location or 'San Diego' in location or 'San Fernando' in location or 'San Francisco' in location or 'San Gabriel' in location or 'San Jose' in location or 'San Juan Capistrano' in location or 'San Leandro' in location or 'San Luis Obispo' in location or 'San Marino' in location or 'San Mateo' in location or 'San Pedro' in location or 'San Rafael' in location or 'San Simeon' in location or 'Santa Ana' in location or 'Santa Barbara' in location or 'Santa Clara' in location or 'Santa Clarita' in location or 'Santa Cruz' in location or 'Santa Monica' in location or 'Santa Rosa' in location or 'Sausalito' in location or 'Simi Valley' in location or 'Sonoma' in location or 'South San Francisco' in location or 'Stockton' in location or 'Sunnyvale' in location or 'Susanville' in location or 'Thousand Oaks' in location or 'Torrance' in location or 'Turlock' in location or 'Ukiah' in location or 'Vallejo' in location or 'Ventura' in location or 'Victorville' in location or 'Visalia' in location or 'Walnut Creek' in location or 'Watts' in location or 'West Covina' in location or 'Whittier' in location or 'Woodland' in location or 'Yorba Linda' in location or 'Yuba City' in location or 'Colorado' in location or 'Alamosa' in location or 'Aspen' in location or 'Aurora' in location or 'Boulder' in location or 'Breckenridge' in location or 'Brighton' in location or 'Canon City' in location or 'Central City' in location or 'Climax' in location or 'Colorado Springs' in location or 'Cortez' in location or 'Cripple Creek' in location or 'Denver' in location or 'Durango' in location or 'Englewood' in location or 'Estes Park' in location or 'Fort Collins' in location or 'Fort Morgan' in location or 'Georgetown' in location or 'Glenwood Springs' in location or 'Golden' in location or 'Grand Junction' in location or 'Greeley' in location or 'Gunnison' in location or 'La Junta' in location or 'Leadville' in location or 'Littleton' in location or 'Longmont' in location or 'Loveland' in location or 'Montrose' in location or 'Ouray' in location or 'Pagosa Springs' in location or 'Pueblo' in location or 'Silverton' in location or 'Steamboat Springs' in location or 'Sterling' in location or 'Telluride' in location or 'Trinidad' in location or 'Vail' in location or 'Walsenburg' in location or 'Westminster' in location or 'Connecticut' in location or 'Ansonia' in location or 'Berlin' in location or 'Bloomfield' in location or 'Branford' in location or 'Bridgeport' in location or 'Bristol' in location or 'Coventry' in location or 'Danbury' in location or 'Darien' in location or 'Derby' in location or 'East Hartford' in location or 'East Haven' in location or 'Enfield' in location or 'Fairfield' in location or 'Farmington' in location or 'Greenwich' in location or 'Groton' in location or 'Guilford' in location or 'Hamden' in location or 'Hartford' in location or 'Lebanon' in location or 'Litchfield' in location or 'Manchester' in location or 'Mansfield' in location or 'Meriden' in location or 'Middletown' in location or 'Milford' in location or 'Mystic' in location or 'Naugatuck' in location or 'New Britain' in location or 'New Haven' in location or 'New London' in location or 'North Haven' in location or 'Norwalk' in location or 'Norwich' in location or 'Old Saybrook' in location or 'Orange' in location or 'Seymour' in location or 'Shelton' in location or 'Simsbury' in location or 'Southington' in location or 'Stamford' in location or 'Stonington' in location or 'Stratford' in location or 'Torrington' in location or 'Wallingford' in location or 'Waterbury' in location or 'Waterford' in location or 'Watertown' in location or 'West Hartford' in location or 'West Haven' in location or 'Westport' in location or 'Wethersfield' in location or 'Willimantic' in location or 'Windham' in location or 'Windsor' in location or 'Windsor Locks' in location or 'Winsted' in location or 'Delaware' in location or 'Dover' in location or 'Lewes' in location or 'Milford' in location or 'New Castle' in location or 'Newark' in location or 'Smyrna' in location or 'Wilmington' in location or 'Florida' in location or 'Apalachicola' in location or 'Bartow' in location or 'Belle Glade' in location or 'Boca Raton' in location or 'Bradenton' in location or 'Cape Coral' in location or 'Clearwater' in location or 'Cocoa Beach' in location or 'Cocoa-Rockledge' in location or 'Coral Gables' in location or 'Daytona Beach' in location or 'De Land' in location or 'Deerfield Beach' in location or 'Delray Beach' in location or 'Fernandina Beach' in location or 'Fort Lauderdale' in location or 'Fort Myers' in location or 'Fort Pierce' in location or 'Fort Walton Beach' in location or 'Gainesville' in location or 'Hallandale Beach' in location or 'Hialeah' in location or 'Hollywood' in location or 'Homestead' in location or 'Jacksonville' in location or 'Key West' in location or 'Lake City' in location or 'Lake Wales' in location or 'Lakeland' in location or 'Largo' in location or 'Melbourne' in location or 'Miami' in location or 'Miami Beach' in location or 'Naples' in location or 'New Smyrna Beach' in location or 'Ocala' in location or 'Orlando' in location or 'Ormond Beach' in location or 'Palatka' in location or 'Palm Bay' in location or 'Palm Beach' in location or 'Panama City' in location or 'Pensacola' in location or 'Pompano Beach' in location or 'Saint Augustine' in location or 'Saint Petersburg' in location or 'Sanford' in location or 'Sarasota' in location or 'Sebring' in location or 'Tallahassee' in location or 'Tampa' in location or 'Tarpon Springs' in location or 'Titusville' in location or 'Venice' in location or 'West Palm Beach' in location or 'White Springs' in location or 'Winter Haven' in location or 'Winter Park' in location or 'Georgia' in location or 'Albany' in location or 'Americus' in location or 'Andersonville' in location or 'Athens' in location or 'Atlanta' in location or 'Augusta' in location or 'Bainbridge' in location or 'Blairsville' in location or 'Brunswick' in location or 'Calhoun' in location or 'Carrollton' in location or 'Columbus' in location or 'Dahlonega' in location or 'Dalton' in location or 'Darien' in location or 'Decatur' in location or 'Douglas' in location or 'East Point' in location or 'Fitzgerald' in location or 'Fort Valley' in location or 'Gainesville' in location or 'La Grange' in location or 'Macon' in location or 'Marietta' in location or 'Milledgeville' in location or 'Plains' in location or 'Rome' in location or 'Savannah' in location or 'Toccoa' in location or 'Valdosta' in location or 'Warm Springs' in location or 'Warner Robins' in location or 'Washington' in location or 'Waycross' in location or 'Hawaii' in location or 'Hanalei' in location or 'Hilo' in location or 'Honaunau' in location or 'Honolulu' in location or 'Kahului' in location or 'Kaneohe' in location or 'Kapaa' in location or 'Kawaihae' in location or 'Lahaina' in location or 'Laie' in location or 'Wahiawa' in location or 'Wailuku' in location or 'Waimea' in location or 'Idaho' in location or 'Blackfoot' in location or 'Boise' in location or 'Bonners Ferry' in location or 'Caldwell' in location or 'Coeur d’Alene' in location or 'Idaho City' in location or 'Idaho Falls' in location or 'Kellogg' in location or 'Lewiston' in location or 'Moscow' in location or 'Nampa' in location or 'Pocatello' in location or 'Priest River' in location or 'Rexburg' in location or 'Sun Valley' in location or 'Twin Falls' in location or 'Illinois' in location or 'Alton' in location or 'Arlington Heights' in location or 'Arthur' in location or 'Aurora' in location or 'Belleville' in location or 'Belvidere' in location or 'Bloomington' in location or 'Brookfield' in location or 'Cahokia' in location or 'Cairo' in location or 'Calumet City' in location or 'Canton' in location or 'Carbondale' in location or 'Carlinville' in location or 'Carthage' in location or 'Centralia' in location or 'Champaign' in location or 'Charleston' in location or 'Chester' in location or 'Chicago' in location or 'Chicago Heights' in location or 'Cicero' in location or 'Collinsville' in location or 'Danville' in location or 'Decatur' in location or 'DeKalb' in location or 'Des Plaines' in location or 'Dixon' in location or 'East Moline' in location or 'East Saint Louis' in location or 'Effingham' in location or 'Elgin' in location or 'Elmhurst' in location or 'Evanston' in location or 'Freeport' in location or 'Galena' in location or 'Galesburg' in location or 'Glen Ellyn' in location or 'Glenview' in location or 'Granite City' in location or 'Harrisburg' in location or 'Herrin' in location or 'Highland Park' in location or 'Jacksonville' in location or 'Joliet' in location or 'Kankakee' in location or 'Kaskaskia' in location or 'Kewanee' in location or 'La Salle' in location or 'Lake Forest' in location or 'Libertyville' in location or 'Lincoln' in location or 'Lisle' in location or 'Lombard' in location or 'Macomb' in location or 'Mattoon' in location or 'Moline' in location or 'Monmouth' in location or 'Mount Vernon' in location or 'Mundelein' in location or 'Naperville' in location or 'Nauvoo' in location or 'Normal' in location or 'North Chicago' in location or 'Oak Park' in location or 'Oregon' in location or 'Ottawa' in location or 'Palatine' in location or 'Park Forest' in location or 'Park Ridge' in location or 'Pekin' in location or 'Peoria' in location or 'Petersburg' in location or 'Pontiac' in location or 'Quincy' in location or 'Rantoul' in location or 'River Forest' in location or 'Rock Island' in location or 'Rockford' in location or 'Salem' in location or 'Shawneetown' in location or 'Skokie' in location or 'South Holland' in location or 'Springfield' in location or 'Streator' in location or 'Summit' in location or 'Urbana' in location or 'Vandalia' in location or 'Virden' in location or 'Waukegan' in location or 'Wheaton' in location or 'Wilmette' in location or 'Winnetka' in location or 'Wood River' in location or 'Zion' in location or 'Indiana' in location or 'Anderson' in location or 'Bedford' in location or 'Bloomington' in location or 'Columbus' in location or 'Connersville' in location or 'Corydon' in location or 'Crawfordsville' in location or 'East Chicago' in location or 'Elkhart' in location or 'Elwood' in location or 'Evansville' in location or 'Fort Wayne' in location or 'French Lick' in location or 'Gary' in location or 'Geneva' in location or 'Goshen' in location or 'Greenfield' in location or 'Hammond' in location or 'Hobart' in location or 'Huntington' in location or 'Indianapolis' in location or 'Jeffersonville' in location or 'Kokomo' in location or 'Lafayette' in location or 'Madison' in location or 'Marion' in location or 'Michigan City' in location or 'Mishawaka' in location or 'Muncie' in location or 'Nappanee' in location or 'Nashville' in location or 'New Albany' in location or 'New Castle' in location or 'New Harmony' in location or 'Peru' in location or 'Plymouth' in location or 'Richmond' in location or 'Santa Claus' in location or 'Shelbyville' in location or 'South Bend' in location or 'Terre Haute' in location or 'Valparaiso' in location or 'Vincennes' in location or 'Wabash' in location or 'West Lafayette' in location or 'Iowa' in location or 'Amana Colonies' in location or 'Ames' in location or 'Boone' in location or 'Burlington' in location or 'Cedar Falls' in location or 'Cedar Rapids' in location or 'Charles City' in location or 'Cherokee' in location or 'Clinton' in location or 'Council Bluffs' in location or 'Davenport' in location or 'Des Moines' in location or 'Dubuque' in location or 'Estherville' in location or 'Fairfield' in location or 'Fort Dodge' in location or 'Grinnell' in location or 'Indianola' in location or 'Iowa City' in location or 'Keokuk' in location or 'Mason City' in location or 'Mount Pleasant' in location or 'Muscatine' in location or 'Newton' in location or 'Oskaloosa' in location or 'Ottumwa' in location or 'Sioux City' in location or 'Waterloo' in location or 'Webster City' in location or 'West Des Moines' in location or 'Kansas' in location or 'Abilene' in location or 'Arkansas City' in location or 'Atchison' in location or 'Chanute' in location or 'Coffeyville' in location or 'Council Grove' in location or 'Dodge City' in location or 'Emporia' in location or 'Fort Scott' in location or 'Garden City' in location or 'Great Bend' in location or 'Hays' in location or 'Hutchinson' in location or 'Independence' in location or 'Junction City' in location or 'Kansas City' in location or 'Lawrence' in location or 'Leavenworth' in location or 'Liberal' in location or 'Manhattan' in location or 'McPherson' in location or 'Medicine Lodge' in location or 'Newton' in location or 'Olathe' in location or 'Osawatomie' in location or 'Ottawa' in location or 'Overland Park' in location or 'Pittsburg' in location or 'Salina' in location or 'Shawnee' in location or 'Smith Center' in location or 'Topeka' in location or 'Wichita' in location or 'Kentucky' in location or 'Ashland' in location or 'Barbourville' in location or 'Bardstown' in location or 'Berea' in location or 'Boonesborough' in location or 'Bowling Green' in location or 'Campbellsville' in location or 'Covington' in location or 'Danville' in location or 'Elizabethtown' in location or 'Frankfort' in location or 'Harlan' in location or 'Harrodsburg' in location or 'Hazard' in location or 'Henderson' in location or 'Hodgenville' in location or 'Hopkinsville' in location or 'Lexington' in location
```

After that, I was thinking to add exception like,

```
'PA' in location and location != ‘PARIS'
```

but this one also impossible because of the limit.. please help me

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would want to use a set, and the `in` membership operator for this:

```
allowed_locations = {
    'Alabama',
    'Alaska',
    # etc
}

def is_allowed_location(location):
    return location in allowed_locations
```

This will detect if `location` is actually one of the listed locations. If you really want to ask if `location` is *included* in one of the listed locations, then this code is equivalent to yours (using a list here because set gives no benefits but takes up more memory):

```
allowed_locations = [
    'Alabama',
    'Alaska',
    # etc
]

def is_allowed_location(location):
    return any(allowed_location in location
               for allowed_location in allowed_locations)
```

Comment: @ewong: No, list gets square brackets, set gets curlies. However, I just noticed that the answer is not doing the same thing the question code is...

Comment: set are curlies?  I thought they were ()?

Comment: OH, it's really helpful thank you so much, but I just added question regarding the adding exception, can you give me help for that part..?

Comment: @ewong no, that's a tuple. `{}` are for both sets and dicts.

Comment: colour me enlightened.

Comment: @Rachelle You would need to be explicit; I don't know how to answer that.For example, how does your Paris example interact with the example above it? Is there a list of exceptions for each allowed location, or...

Answer (score 0):

You wish to know whether `any` particular `location` taken from a given set of `allowed_locations` is `in` a given `location_text`; the needed Python code is almost as direct:

```
allowed_locations = {
    'Alabama', 'Alaska', # etc.
    # while inside the curly brackets that make the `set`, we can wrap lines.
}

# we test as:
any(location in location_text for location in allowed_locations)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The simplest way would probably be to use a list and the **contains** function.

```
# I put all the names in this list.
list_of_names = ['New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'West Virginia', 'new hampshire', 'new jersey', 'new mexico', 'new york', 'north carolina', 'north dakota', 'rhode island', 'south carolina', 'south dakota', 'west Virginia', 'Alexander City', 'Fort Payne', 'Phenix City', 'Casa Grande', 'Gila Bend', 'Havasu City', 'Sierra Vista', 'Window Rock', 'Arkansas Post', 'El Dorado', 'Forrest City', 'Fort Smith', 'Hot Springs', 'Little Rock', 'Little Rock', 'Pine Bluff', 'Van Buren', 'West Memphis', 'Beverly Hills', 'Buena Park', 'Chula Vista', 'Costa Mesa', 'Culver City', 'Daly City', 'El Centro', 'El Cerrito', 'El Monte', 'Garden Grove', 'Huntington Beach', 'La Habra', 'Laguna Beach', 'Long Beach', 'Los Angeles', 'Menlo Park', 'Mountain View', 'Newport Beach', 'Pacific Grove', 'Palm Springs', 'Palo Alto', 'Port Hueneme', 'Rancho Cucamonga', 'Red Bluff', 'Redondo Beach', 'Redwood City', 'San Bernardino', 'San Clemente', 'San Diego', 'San Fernando', 'San Francisco', 'San Gabriel', 'San Jose', 'Juan Capistrano', 'San Leandro', 'Luis Obispo', 'San Marino', 'San Mateo', 'San Pedro', 'San Rafael', 'San Simeon', 'Santa Ana', 'Santa Barbara', 'Santa Clara', 'Santa Clarita', 'Santa Cruz', 'Santa Monica', 'Santa Rosa', 'Simi Valley', 'San Francisco', 'Thousand Oaks', 'Walnut Creek', 'West Covina', 'Yorba Linda', 'Yuba City', 'Canon City', 'Central City', 'Colorado Springs', 'Cripple Creek', 'Estes Park', 'Fort Collins', 'Fort Morgan', 'Glenwood Springs', 'Grand Junction', 'La Junta', 'Pagosa Springs', 'Steamboat Springs', 'East Hartford', 'East Haven', 'New Britain', 'New Haven', 'New London', 'North Haven', 'Old Saybrook', 'West Hartford', 'West Haven', 'Windsor Locks', 'New Castle', 'Belle Glade', 'Boca Raton', 'Cape Coral', 'Cocoa Beach', 'Coral Gables', 'Daytona Beach', 'De Land', 'Deerfield Beach', 'Delray Beach', 'Fernandina Beach', 'Fort Lauderdale', 'Fort Myers', 'Fort Pierce', 'Walton Beach', 'Hallandale Beach', 'Key West', 'Lake City', 'Lake Wales', 'Miami Beach', 'Smyrna Beach', 'Ormond Beach', 'Palm Bay', 'Palm Beach', 'Panama City', 'Pompano Beach', 'Saint Augustine', 'Saint Petersburg', 'Tarpon Springs', 'Palm Beach', 'White Springs', 'Winter Haven', 'Winter Park', 'East Point', 'Fort Valley', 'La Grange', 'Warm Springs', 'Warner Robins', 'Bonners Ferry', 'Idaho City', 'Idaho Falls', 'Priest River', 'Sun Valley', 'Twin Falls', 'Arlington Heights', 'Calumet City', 'Chicago Heights', 'Des Plaines', 'East Moline', 'Saint Louis', 'Glen Ellyn', 'Granite City', 'Highland Park', 'La Salle', 'Lake Forest', 'Mount Vernon', 'North Chicago', 'Oak Park', 'Park Forest', 'Park Ridge', 'River Forest', 'Rock Island', 'South Holland', 'Wood River', 'East Chicago', 'Fort Wayne', 'French Lick', 'Michigan City', 'New Albany', 'New Castle', 'New Harmony', 'Santa Claus', 'South Bend', 'Terre Haute', 'West Lafayette', 'Amana Colonies', 'Cedar Falls', 'Cedar Rapids', 'Charles City', 'Council Bluffs', 'Des Moines', 'Fort Dodge', 'Iowa City', 'Mason City', 'Mount Pleasant', 'Sioux City', 'Webster City', 'Des Moines', 'Arkansas City', 'Council Grove', 'Dodge City', 'Fort Scott', 'Garden City', 'Great Bend', 'Junction City', 'Kansas City', 'Medicine Lodge', 'Overland Park', 'Smith Center', 'Bowling Green']


def is_allowed_location(location):  # I'm guessing we're supposed to put a name, as a str, for location.

    # Check to see it location is in the list.
    if list_of_names.__contains__(location):

        # If location is one of the cities, return the name as a str. If it's not in the list, return None.
        return location  # OR you could just return list_of_names.__contains__(location) without the if statement to return a boolean.


print(is_allowed_location("New Mexico"))  # Test. --> "New Mexico"
print(is_allowed_location("Mayberry"))  # Test. --> None
```